# Watir browser process doesn't start properly (Windows)

Tags: ruby, windows, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I've built a simple script in Linux, but now I'm trying to get it to work on windows.

The code is:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
puts "Press enter when ready to continue"
gets
browser = Watir::Browser.start "http://www.google.com"
# do stuff
```

It works exactly as expected on Ubuntu. But when I try it on Windows, the Firefox process starts, but then dies before you even see a Firefox window. This is a fresh install of Ruby on this Windows installation, I've never used it before on this machine.

What could be the problem?

Edit: Command line trace, as requested.

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:90:in `connect_until_stable': unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:55:in `block in launch'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:43:in `locked'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:51:in `launch'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:43:in `initialize'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:53:in `new'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:53:in `for'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:84:in `for'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from bot.rb:8:in `new'
    from bot.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Is there an exception?

Comment: Adding to Justin's question, what's the error trace on command line ? Sounds most likely an incompatibility between selenium-webdriver (in WATIR) and the FF version installed on your machine.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Hmm, that could be possible. It should be mentioned, I do have Waterfox also installed (but not chrome, I couldn't get the installer to work) and several FF profiles (though I've tried selecting a specific one with no luck).

I've edited the post with the command line trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [this bug](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2110) in Firefox. Your options are:

1. Wait for the patch in Firefox 47
2. Downgrade to Firefox 46
3. Use Marionette instead of the Firefox Driver (which is being deprecated and won't work with new versions of Firefox soon)
4. Use Chrome

To try marionette, download the [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and do:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, marionette: true
```

Comment: Aha, brilliant to know, I'm glad it wasn't just me being stupid! Thanks very much for your help. I've gone with option 5. build something on Rails using a headless browser to do it. Something for the portfolio I guess!

Thanks again.